# Not able to understand fold() behavior in spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to spark. I have executed the following spark program,

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("FoldFunction").master("local").getOrCreate()
    val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("Maths", 10), ("English", 10), ("Social", 10), ("Science",10)))
    val extraMarks = ("extra", 10)
    val foldedData = data.fold(extraMarks){ (acc, marks) => val add = acc._2 + marks._2
      ("total", add)}

    println(foldedData)
```

As per my analysis, code will add 10 marks to total sum of marks. But I am getting answer as `(total,60)`.

Could anyone explain me how, whether my analysis is correct or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api document says the following

> `* @param zeroValue the initial value for the accumulated result of each partition for the`op`operator, and also the initial value for the combine results from different partitions for the`op`operator - this will typically be the neutral element (e.g.`Nil`for list concatenation or`0`for summation)
>      * @param op an operator used to both accumulate results within a partition and combine results from different partitions
>      */
>     def fold(zeroValue: T)(op: (T, T) => T): T`

Usually `zeroValue` is set to `0` or `Nil`

But your `zeroValue` is `("extra", 10)` which is added in the last accumulation process again and thats how you get `(total,60)`

Lets go step by step

at first `acc` is `(extra,10)` `marks` is `(Maths,10)` so *10+10=20* i.e. `(total, 20)`
second `acc` is `(total,20)` `marks` is `(English,10)` so *20+10=30* i.e. `(total, 30)`
third `acc` is `(total,30)` `marks` is `(Social,10)` so *30+10=40* i.e. `(total, 40)`
fourth `acc` is `(total,40)` `marks` is `(Science,10)` so *40+10=50* i.e. `(total, 50)`
accumulation adds `zeroValue` `(extra,10)` with the `folded` `(total,50)` so *10+50=60* i.e. `(total, 60)`

Comment: Could you please explain in more details? but still i feel result should be 50.